# Does apache olingo have client class generator?

Tags: java, apache, olingo

Does this feature exists? If it does, it would be really nice to give me at least an idea how to do it... or maybe at least give me a documentation link so I can work on implementing it on the project I am working on. Because I can't seem to find any resources to implement this...

Comment: No comment to let me know why this question is down voted? Because I really have to know so I can improve this question into an appropriate one if it isn't appropriate for the standards of this site